# Whats this "c:" all about?

Tags: jsp, jstl

I'm very inexperienced with JSP, and have come across a section of what I assume is JS (or some variant of it at least?) it goes as such:

```
<c:forEach items="${errorsMap}" var="messages" varStatus="status">
```

and another example of what I assume is a different function:

```
<c:set var="errorsArePresent" value="true" />
```

I assume that that the forEach one is to provide a loop through every element in a list (in this case errorsMap, and that 'set' sets a variable to the variable, what I am seeking clarification on is why these lines have c: in front of them? What does it mean?

If it helps, this script is contained in a JSP and is in amongst a  container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the **prefix** that has been used when including the JSTL Core library, likely something like this:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

...so when referencing functions from that library, you prefix it with the `c:` to distinguish it from other potential function name conflicts.

See [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm)

Comment: I see, the file I am currently rifling through has these tags in, but does not appear to have a line at the start of the file like you included in your post.
However, it does include `<%@ include file={file location}%>` which is a file I do not currently have. Is it possible the declaration of the JSTL tag is in that file and it is inherited by this file?

Comment: It could just be included in another file that your file is including.  EDIT: Just saw your edit to your comment above.  Yeah that is likely the case.

Comment: I've managed to get access to that file. Yep, that's the case!

Answer (score 3):

It's the JSTL core library ([documentation)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/tld-summary.html).

Nothing to do with JavaScript, JSTL means "JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library", i.e. a taglib extending the JSP specification (more info on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages_Standard_Tag_Library)).

Answer (score 1):

It is JSTL Core tags(JSP Standard Tag Library). You can check documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakc.html